# contar quantas vezes a palavra carregada do arquivo txt aparece python

Tags: python

Preciso fazer um programa em que eu salvo um arquivo txt, depois abro e leio ele. Até ai tudo bem. Mas não sei como fazer para mostrar quantas vezes aparece cada palavra do texto aberto aparece.

Ex: O texto aparece a palavra mil 5 vezes, a palavra casa 7 vezes e etc. Como faço pra ler o que está dentro do texto, sem precisar criar uma lista pra isso?

Comment: Queres contar apenas quantas vezes aparece uma palavra em especifíco no ficheiro?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss também pensei nisso, mas acho que esta pode ir por um caminho não tão trabalhoso. A outra implicava a abertura de dois arquivos e processamento dos dados entre eles

Comment: carro casa chocolate prato colher tapete chapa tapete prato prato chocolate
from collections import Counterwith open('/Users/DIGITAL/Desktop/Python/teste.txt') as f:
ocorrencias = Counter(f.read().split())
print(ocorrencias)


As palavras que estao no texto foram essas, so que na hora de ordenar,preciso que apareça em ordem crescente, ta aparecendo assim: choclocate 3 vzs, casa 2.. e eu preciso que apareça ao contrário, do menor para o maior

Comment: Olá acho que deves fazer uma nova pergunta independente desta, essa parte não faz parte nem está de todo comtemplada nesta pergunta/resposta. É melhor apagares o que fizeste em baixo visto que é um espaço exclusivo para respostas. Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para contar uma palavra podes fazer assim:

```
palavra = 'casa'
with open('arquivo.txt') as f:
    ocorrencias = f.read().count(palavra)
print(ocorrencias) # num de vezes que a palavra aparece
```

Feito isto, se quiseres contar todas a ocorrências de todas as palavras:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('arquivo.txt') as f:
    ocorrencias = Counter(f.read().split())
print(ocorrencias) # num de vezes que as palavras aparecem
```

NOTA: nesta ultima cria-se uma lista explicíta quando `f.read().split()`, apesar de não darmos por ela